# How to examine or analyze an index

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm getting started with Lucene.Net but by ultimate goal here isn't to actually implement search (at least, not right now), but to be able to index a document and then analyze the index to find things like the most frequently occurring terms.

For example, I have this:

```
Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new Lucene.Net.Analysis.Standard.StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
var LDoc = new Lucene.Net.Documents.Document();
LDoc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("header", header, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.ANALYZED));
LDoc.Add(new Lucene.Net.Documents.Field("summary", summary, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Store.YES, Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.Index.ANALYZED));
var ram = new Lucene.Net.Store.RAMDirectory();
using (var iWriter = new Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter(ram, analyzer, Lucene.Net.Index.IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED))
{
    iWriter.AddDocument(LDoc);
}
```

And this runs and doesn't complain. But what I'm not getting from the spotty documentation I've been able to find is how I can now example the index to see what's in it.

Let's say, for example, I want to pull out which terms are in the index with their frequency. Is there a way to do that?

**Edit**: A little more digging and it looks like what I really need to look at is an `IndexReader`. So I can do this:

```
using (var iReader = Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Open(ram, true)) 
{
    var tEnumerator = iReader.Terms();
    while (tEnumerator.Next())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", tEnumerator.Term, tEnumerator.DocFreq());
    }
}
```

And this will show me each term, but `DocFreq` is the number of *documents* it appears in, not the number of times it appears *in any particular document*. So, digging around some more it seems like what I really need is:

```
var vect = iReader.GetTermFreqVectors(0);
```

But for some reason, this is always returning `null`. So what am I still missing?

Comment: That returns `null` because none of your fields are indexed with TermVectors.  You can set it to store TermVectors by passing an appropriate value (ex. `Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.TermVector.YES`) into the [`Field` constructor](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/da7/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_documents_1_1_field.html#abb2d635c30101749c77eb050ccc45f18).

Comment: @femtoRgon: Thanks, you are correct. If you post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: All right.  Wasn't sure if that entirely solved the remaining problems for you, but if it does it, I'll go ahead and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetTermFreqVectors` returns null because none of your fields are indexed with TermVectors.

You can set it to store TermVectors by passing a member of the [`TermVector` enum](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/da7/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_documents_1_1_field.html#a3b16afc1c9c84681505db09934edd40e) (ex. `Lucene.Net.Documents.Field.TermVector.YES`) into the [Field constructor](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/de/da7/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_documents_1_1_field.html#abb2d635c30101749c77eb050ccc45f18).